# Java Split on Regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I cant seem to be able to split on a simple regex,

If i have a string `[data, data2]` and i attempt to split like so: I tried to escape the brackets.

```
    String regex = "\\[,\\]";
    String[] notifySplit = notifyWho.split(regex);
```

The output of looping through notifySplit shows this regex not working

```
notify: [Everyone, Teachers only]
```

Any help on what the proper regex is, i am expecting an array like so:
    data, data2

where i could possibly ignore these two characters `[ ,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't want to *split* on the brackets. You just want to exclude them from your end result. So first thing you'll probably want to do is strip those out:

```
notifyWho = notifyWho.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Then you can do a basic split on the comma:

```
String[] notifySplit = notifyWho.split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in one line, first removing the square brackets, then splitting:

```
String[] notifySplit = notifyWho.replaceAll("[[\\]]", "").split(",");
```